# Word Automation

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, automation

I try to write in a word document at a bookmark location. I can add lines of text but i would like to add multiple lines with multiple fonts, sizes etc.
I think i need to add multiple paragraphs but how ?

Here is my working code sofar.

```
Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
oWord.Visible = True
Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add
Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add("D:\MyDocument.dotx")     'Based on a template
oDoc.Bookmarks("OFFER").Range.Text = "First Line of text" & vbcrlf & "Second line of text"
```

I want the second line in a different font size.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can do it:

```
Dim oDoc as Document = oWord.Documents.Add("D:\MyDocument.dotx")

Dim range As Range = oDoc.Bookmarks("OFFER").Range

//Add paragraph 1
Dim paragraph1 As Paragraph = range.Paragraphs.Add()

paragraph1.Range.Text = "First Line of text"

paragraph1.Range.Font.Size = 30

//Add paragraph2 after paragraph 1
Dim paragraph2 As Paragraph = paragraph1.Range.Paragraphs.Add()

paragraph2.Range.Text = "Second line of text"

paragraph2.Range.Font.Size = 50
```